# Meteor Installation issue on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, meteor

I try to install Meteor JS using "curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh", my system says that meteor only supports 64-bit processors and stops the the installation.

```
Only 64-bit intel processors are supported at this time
```

As far as I know my system is 64-bit (Mac OS X 10.9.1 *Darwin 13.0.0*) and has had meteor working on it perfectly fine in the past.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: what does `uname -a` say?

Comment: "uname -a": Darwin mathbook 13.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue on "Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0" and I looked in their installation code(as of Wed Apr 1 2015). The problem is that, at least in my case,  they assume ***sysctl*** is in your path, but it's not.

```
 if [ "i386" != "$(uname -p)" -o "1" != "$(sysctl -n hw.cpu64bit_capable 2>/dev/null || echo 0)" ] ; then
```

The solution is very simple

```
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH && curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

You will need to add /usr/sbin/sysctl to your path too **PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH**, otherwise you may run into the same issue when runing the following command

```
meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone facing this issue in mac with m1 chip try this commands

**arch -x86_64 zsh**

**curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh**

It will resolve your problem.

The meteor command will work fine , but upon closing the terminal and trying again the command `meteor` did n't worked for me , but using  **arch -x86_64 zsh** first and then `meteor` command worked